# Apache Flink throws "Partition already finished" exceptions

Tags: exception, kubernetes, apache-flink, partition

We are running Apache Flink 1.9 in Kubernetes. We have a few jobs that consume Kafka events and collect the counts every minute. The jobs have been working quite well, but recently there are suddenly numerous errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Partition already finished.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:727)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:310)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:409)
```

The code that throws the error is from a Listener that gets events and emits watermark.

```
    // We use an underlying API lib to get a source Context from Flink, sorry not to have source code here
    import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
    protected var context: SourceFunction.SourceContext[T] = ...

    validEventsSorted.foreach { event =>
      try {
        context.collectWithTimestamp(event, event.occurredAt.toEpochMilli)
        context.emitWatermark(new Watermark(event.occurredAt.minusSeconds(30).toEpochMilli))
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          logger.error(
              s"Failed to add to context. Event EID: ${event.nakadiMetaData.eid}." +
                s" Event: $event",
              e
            )
      }

    }
```

Restarting Flink job manager and task manager will end the errors, but this issue may come again later.

As I understand and guess, the `Partition already finished` is caused when an operator tries to deliver the events to next operator (partition), but I do not understand how this could happen.

And here is our code on Source

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichParallelSourceFunction

class SourceImpl[T: ClassTag](
    listener: KafkaListener[T]
)
extends RichParallelSourceFunction[T] {

  @volatile private var isCancelled: Boolean = false

  @volatile private var consumerFuture: java.util.concurrent.Future[_] = _

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[T]): Unit = {
    
    while (!isCancelled) {
        val runnable = KafkaClient
          .stream(subscription)
          .withStreamParameters(streamParameters)
          .runnable(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], listener)

        val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        consumerFuture = executorService.submit(runnable)
        consumerFuture.get() // This is blocking
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          logger.warn(s"Unknown error consuming events", e)
      }
    }
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    isCancelled = true
    consumerFuture.cancel(true)
  }
}
```

Anybody has any idea why and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you share the complete user code and also logs of a run where the exception occurred with us?

Comment: @TillRohrmann sorry for my late response. I updated the question, and I thought I may find the reason, so I posted an answer below. If you have any question or comment on my answer, please comment. Appreciate very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there is a bug in our `SourceImpl`.  When this job is cancelled by JobManager, `cancel` method is called but may fail and `executorService` is not shutdown and the `runnable` is still running in TaskManager, which consumes events and emits WaterMark. Since the job is already marked as cancelled in JobManager and TaskManager, the watermark emission will lead to `Partition already finished` exception.

So, we made a fix to shutdown `ExecutoreService` explicitly

```
    // Shutdown executorService
    if (executorService != null && !executorService.isShutdown) {
      executorService.shutdownNow()
    }
```

The full code is below

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichParallelSourceFunction

class SourceImpl[T: ClassTag](
    listener: KafkaListener[T]
)
extends RichParallelSourceFunction[T] {

  @volatile private var isCancelled: Boolean = false

  @volatile private var consumerFuture: java.util.concurrent.Future[_] = _

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[T]): Unit = {
    
    val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
  
    while (!isCancelled) {
        val runnable = KafkaClient
          .stream(subscription)
          .withStreamParameters(streamParameters)
          .runnable(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], listener)

        consumerFuture = executorService.submit(runnable)
        consumerFuture.get() // This is blocking
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          logger.warn(s"Unknown error consuming events", e)
      }
    }

    // Shutdown executorService
    if (executorService != null && !executorService.isShutdown) {
      executorService.shutdownNow()
    }
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
    isCancelled = true
    consumerFuture.cancel(true)
  }
}
```

BTW, the reason why we have a new `ExecutorService` is to run the listener in a separate thread pool, which would not affect Flink thread pool.